# Apache Curator - Zookeeper connection loss exception, possible memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, distributed-computing, apache-curator, apache-zookeeper

I have been working on a process that continuously monitors a distributed atomic long counter. It monitors it every minute using the following class `ZkClient`'s method `getCounter`. In fact, I have multiple threads running each of which are monitoring a different counter (distributed atomic long) stored in the Zookeeper nodes. Each thread specifies the path of the counter via the parameters of the `getCounter` method.

```
public class TagserterZookeeperManager {

public enum ZkClient {
    COUNTER("10.11.18.25:2181");  // Integration URL

    private CuratorFramework client;
    private ZkClient(String servers) {
        Properties props = TagserterConfigs.ZOOKEEPER.getProperties();
        String zkFromConfig = props.getProperty("servers", "");
        if (zkFromConfig != null && !zkFromConfig.isEmpty()) {
            servers = zkFromConfig.trim();
        }
        ExponentialBackoffRetry exponentialBackoffRetry = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3);
        client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(servers, exponentialBackoffRetry);
        client.start();
    }

    public CuratorFramework getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}

public static String buildPath(String ... node) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
        if (node[i] != null && !node[i].isEmpty()) {
            sb.append("/");
            sb.append(node[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static DistributedAtomicLong getCounter(String taskType, int hid, String jobId, String countType) {
    String path = buildPath(taskType, hid+"", jobId, countType);
    Builder builder = PromotedToLock.builder().lockPath(path + "/lock").retryPolicy(new ExponentialBackoffRetry(10, 10));
    DistributedAtomicLong count = new DistributedAtomicLong(ZkClient.COUNTER.getClient(), path, new RetryNTimes(5, 20), builder.build());
    return count;
}

}
```

From within the threads, this is how I am calling this method:

```
    DistributedAtomicLong counterTotal = TagserterZookeeperManager
                        .getCounter("testTopic", hid, jobId, "test");
```

Now it seems like after the threads have run for a few hours, at one stage I start getting the following `org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException` exception inside the `getCounter` method where it tries to read the count:

> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /contentTaskProd
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1073)
>           at org.apache.curator.utils.ZKPaths.mkdirs(ZKPaths.java:215)
>           at org.apache.curator.utils.EnsurePath$InitialHelper$1.call(EnsurePath.java:148)
>           at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
>           at org.apache.curator.utils.EnsurePath$InitialHelper.ensure(EnsurePath.java:141)
>           at org.apache.curator.utils.EnsurePath.ensure(EnsurePath.java:99)
>           at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.atomic.DistributedAtomicValue.getCurrentValue(DistributedAtomicValue.java:254)
>           at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.atomic.DistributedAtomicValue.get(DistributedAtomicValue.java:91)
>           at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.atomic.DistributedAtomicLong.get(DistributedAtomicLong.java:72)
>     ...

I keep getting this exception from thereon for a while and I get the feeling it is causing some internal memory leaks that eventually causes an OutOfMemory error and the whole process bails out. Does anybody have any idea what the reason for this could be? Why would Zookeeper suddenly start throwing the connection loss exception? After the process bails out, I can manually connect to Zookeeper through another small console program that I have written (also using curator) and all look good there.

Comment: Hi, how did you finally resolve this issue? I also seem to be having the same issue even with explicitly calling close() on Curator Framework.

Comment: @SumitNigam Sorry for getting back to you late on this one. Actually I had stopped working on that project and it has been a while since then. It turns out we might need to rewrite and refactor major parts of the project for various other reasons. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to monitor a node in Zookeeper using `curator` you can use the [NodeCache](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/node-cache.html) this won't solve your connection problems.... but instead of polling the node once a minute you can get a push event when it changes.

In my experience, the `NodeCache` handles quite well disconnection and resume of connections.