# ListAzureBlobStorage failed to obtain value from ZooKeeper for component with ID

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper

The ListAzureBlobStorage was working fine with setting: [image: ListAzureBlobStorage configuration].
Until it failed with the below error without anything being changed. I have restarted the nifi and reset all the properties again. However, the error still remains. I have looked into the similar questions: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668062/nifi-fail-to-initialize-processor-when-one-node-in-a-cluster-goes-down), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579279/apache-curator-zookeeper-connection-loss-exception-possible-memory-leak), they do not provide solution to my specific problem.

> ListAzureBlobStorage[id=34c1ea1d-0186-1000-aad1-11c9a28c4c83] Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain value from ZooKeeper for component with ID 34c1ea1d-0186-1000-aad1-11c9a28c4c83 with exception code CONNECTIONLOSS: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /nifi/components/34c1ea1d-0186-1000-aad1-11c9a28c4c83
> ↳ causes: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain value from ZooKeeper for component with ID 34c1ea1d-0186-1000-aad1-11c9a28c4c83 with exception code CONNECTIONLOSS

I appreciate any help and direction to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the above case, nifi was set up using docker. Restarting the zookeeper container helped to resolve this issue.